# Comment delete laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want delete a comment, but when i click, this redirect me to laravel error page and display  `""` that error. Why is happen ?

web.php

```
 Route::post('/comments/destroy/{id}', 'CommentController@destroy')->name('comment.destroy');
```

commentcontroller

```
 public function destroy($id){
    $comment=Comment::where('id',$id)->first();
    $comment->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
  }
```

blade

```
@foreach($comment as $comments)
<form action="{{route('comment.destroy',$comments->id  )}}" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
   <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
   <div class="comment-body"><p>{{ $comments->body }}</p></div>
</form>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` on the html form, you must change the route method to `delete`:

```
Route::delete('/comments/destroy/{id}', 'CommentController@destroy')->name('comment.destroy');
```

But if you want to use `POST` method on the route, you must remove `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` from your form.

Comment: There is a shorter way to do so:
@method('DELETE')